# XamarinとXamarin.Form

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

AndroidアプリをVSで作成するにあたって
XamarinとXamarin.Formはどのように使い分けていますか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xamarin formsはiPhone等への移植を想定しているとき、xamarin androidはiPhone等への移植を想定していないときですかね。
xamarin androidは言語以外ネイティブとほぼ同じなので、デザイナーもありますし、市販のandroidの書籍も役に立ちますので、とっつきやすいと思います。
formsは画面作成時にデザイナーがなく、XAMLで書かなきゃいけないことや、ネイティブのAPIを呼ぶのに一手間かかるので、とっつきにくいかなと思います。ただなれてくれば問題無いと思います。
将来的なことを考えるとformsがいいと思いますが、ちょっとしたアプリを作るのであれば、xamarin androidの方がいいかもしれません。
あくまでも私の主観です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。自分用のアプリなのでxamarin.androidで作成します